# Python password validator

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a basic program that checks if a password meets certain criteria. This isn't returning any errors but gives the 'password verified' message whether there is a special character or not. Any ideas welcome!

```
import re
begin = str(input("Would you like to check your password strength?"))
while begin.lower() == "yes" or begin.lower() == "y":
    password = str(input("Please enter your password"))
    if len(password)<8:
        print ("Your password needs to be at least 8 characters long")
    elif password.isupper() or password.islower():
        print ("Please and include at least one upper and one lower case letter in your password")
    elif password.isnumeric() or password.isalpha():
        print ("Your password should not be numbers only or letters only but should include a mixture of both")
    elif re.match("£$%^&*()",password) == True:
        print ("Your password should contain at least one special character")
    else:
        print ("Password verified")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `re.match()` is flawed on several counts. Rather get into that, though, I would propose a different tactic:

```
elif set("£$%^&*()").isdisjoint(password):
```

This converts your string of special characters into a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set) of characters, then checks to see if it is *disjoint* from the password... that is, if it shares no elements with the password. If that is true, then you know that none of your special characters appear in the password and can proceed accordingly.

Comment: Can use `elif not set("£$%^&*()").intersection(password)` here so you're not explicitly building a `set` from password first...

Comment: @JonClements Is there an advantage to that? Wouldn't `intersection` just convert `password` to a set anyway? (Not sure where to find the code for the `set` class to check.)

Comment: About 25% from what I recall... it looks like it swaps the comparison based on length, removing elements and doesn't have to build a completely new set, see: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L1253

Comment: @JonClements Interesting, didn't know that. Also just noticed [`isdisjoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint), which looks like an even better fit here.